# RangeError: Invalid time value - date-fns

Tags: next.js

I'm doing the nextJs tutorial and have run into a problem with the date.js file.

```
import { parseISO, format } from 'date-fns'

export default function Date({ dateString }) {
  const date = parseISO(dateString)
  return <time dateTime={dateString}>{format(date, 'LLLL d, yyyy')}</time>
}
```

The error is:

[image]

What's wrong with what I did?

Comment: can you change the function name `Date`. it is a reserved word in js.

Comment: The issue may be in the markdown file. The date data from the markdown file may not be parsed properly by the gray-matter parser. Copy the md file once again from the tutorial and it may work. I had the same issue and I fixed the mark-down file by adding the missing parts in it.

Answer (score -1):

The issue may be in the markdown file. The date data from the markdown file may not be parsed properly by the gray-matter parser. Copy the md file once again from the tutorial and it may work. I had the same issue and I fixed the mark-down file by adding the missing parts in it.